# Adding a QWidget to a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, widget, qt4, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsScene` for drawing, where I now want to "add" a `QWidget` to a `QGraphicsItem` (display on top of the item, which can of course be moved).

How could this be accomplished? Is there any `QGraphicsItem`, which may function as a Widget container?

Comment: Did you take a look at [`QGraphicsProxyWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `QGraphicsScene::addWidget`  which creates a new `QGraphicsProxyWidget` for widget, adds it to the scene, and returns a pointer to the proxy :

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget * item = myScene->addWidget(myWidget);
item->setParentItem(anOtherItem);
item->setPos(100,100);
item->setZValue(1);
```

Comment: What is that C style cast doing there?